# Convert string to array multidimensional in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I work with socket (server and client), and trying to send a matrix; so I want to send a string array and then convert it to a variable "ARRAY" so for example, if I want to send an array with this structure.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hr3V.jpg]

edit 
`

```
var myString = "[\"Item\", \"Count\"],[\"iPad\",2],[\"Android\",1]";

var arr = JSON.parse("[" + myString + "]");
alert(arr[0][0]);
```

`

i find this example, but no is a multidimensional array, i want call for example School.Section(1).User(1).Name

Comment: You will have to show an example of the string format you receive on the socket and the exact Javascript data format you want it parsed into.  Without that, this question does not contain enough information and will be closed as "Unclear What You Are Asking".  Detail is needed here to offer any meaningful answer.

Comment: var myString = "[\"Item\", \"Count\"],[\"iPad\",2],[\"Android\",1]";

i find this example, but no is a multidimensional array, i want call for example School.Section(1).User(1).Name

Comment: Use the "edit" button to put this code into your question. Multiline code is not legible in comments.  We also need to see what you want the Javascript data structure to look like.  Also, this string is not multi-level like your picture is.

Comment: In case you mistyped the string, you can simply do: `JSON.parse('[[\"Item\", \"Count\"],[\"iPad\",2],[\"Android\",1]]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your structure in JavaScript and try `JSON.stringify` + `JSON.parse`.

Example:

```
var School = {
  Section: [
    {
      User: [
        {
          Name: "John Doe"
        },
        {
          Name: "Jane Doe"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var str = JSON.stringify(School);
// This gives `{"Section":[{"User":[{"Name":"John Doe"},{"Name":"Jane Doe"}]}]}`

var _school = JSON.parse(str);
// This works great!

var name = _school.Section[0].User[1].Name;
// This gives `Jane Doe`.
```